# Login failed for user while connecting to mssql using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to mssql using pyodbc in python and I am using MacOs Mojave. I write the code to make the connection but it gives me the Login failed for user, though I am pretty sure the user and password is correct.

```
import pyodbc
import getpass
server = "servername"
database = 'mydb'
username= 'username'
password = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")
conn = pyodbc.connect(Driver='{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}',
                      Server=server,
                      Database=database,
                      UID=username,
                      pwd=password)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT TOP 100 * FROM my table')
for row in cursor:
    print(row)

conn.close()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/s3480912/Desktop/d2d_Xsell_Propensity/d2d-xsell-score-generator/score_generator.py", line 19, in <module>
    pwd=password)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', u"[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'username'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Comment: It's a login failure from SQL, so at least it's reaching the instance, but the user name or password isn't correct. Can you connect directly to the SQL instance without the pyodbc connector? Or try explicitly setting the value for password and see what it says.

Comment: I am able to use the user and password using "sqlpro for mssql" and it gets connected without any error. I think the problem might be python is choosing windows authentication instead of SQL server authentication and I am not sure how to force it to use sql server authentication.

Comment: It won't arbitrarily choose an authentication method. Windows authentication would require you setting the TrustedConnection parameter and not allow you to pass credentials. Passing a UID and PWD is sql authentication. Is the username you're using actually 'username' or did you update it in your example and in the traceback?